# security context changed in new filesystem

Tags: permissions, selinux

I have `/opt` filesytem and files with security context within:

```
system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0
```

Now I have created another filesystem and mounted it to `/opt/test` and files/folders within it are created with security context:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0
```

How to make the same security context for files in `/opt/test` as are in `/opt` without reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chcon --reference=/opt -R -v /opt/test
```